# Obtener la hora con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo el siguiente codigo, con esto puedo agregar una clase (today) en un div. 
Ahora Lo que necesito es poder hacer lo siguiente,

```
18:00 - 20:00
```

Quiero poder calcular que si el rango de hora no esta entre `18:00 y 20:00`, agregue un texto aun div que diga ( Cerrado ).

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
n = n > 0 ? n - 1 : 6; // zero is sunday, not monday in javascript
$('li.week').eq(n).addClass('today');
```

**UPDATE**

Ahora tengo lo siguiente.

```
var start = new Date('18:00').getTime();
var end = new Date('20:00').getTime();
var now = new Date().getTime();

if( (start < now )) {
  alert("opened");
}
else {
 alert("closed");
}
```

Solo tengo un problema no encuentro la forma de conseguir que se valide la hora con otra.

```
18:00 a 20:00
```

si no esta en ese rango de hora, debe decir Closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes más que usar el método `getHours` para obtener la hora de la fecha.

Algo así:

```js
function comprobarHora(fecha){
  var hora = fecha.getHours();
  console.log(fecha.toLocaleTimeString()
    + (hora>=18 && hora<20 ? ': abierto' : ': cerrado'));
}

var d = new Date();
comprobarHora(d);
d = new Date(2017,12,6,18,54,23);
comprobarHora(d);
d = new Date(2017,12,6,20,17,21);
comprobarHora(d);
```

Comment: usas esto d = new Date(2017,12,6,18,54,23); para comprobar las horas?

Comment: El constructor de fecha es variádico, puedes pasarle también un string del tipo `YYYY-MM-DD` o un ISOString `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss`. Lo que no te servía era pasarle un string de hora. No lo entenderá como "Hoy a las HH:mm hrs"

Comment: No Juan, eso lo utilizo para crear las fechas. Eso lo que hace es crear un objeto a fecha 6/12/2017 18:54:23. La que realiza la comprobación es la función `comprobarHora` extrayendo la hora de la fecha con `getHours` y comprobando que se encuentra entre las 18 y las 20

Comment: Muchas Gracias, cambie un poco el codigo, pero ya me resulto!

Comment: Yo trabajaría con horas en UTC, para que alguien que se meta desde china  sepa que el local está cerrado aunque la hora parezca estar entre las 18 y las 20 de su huso horario. Pero supongo que es la fuerza de la costumbre

Comment: Hey, tengo un 2 problema, me ayudan? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/122937/obtener-la-hora-de-abierto-en-base-a-el-day   , Gracias!