# Obtener la hora de abierto en base a el day

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo el siguiente codigo en HTML

```
Sunday 18:00 - 23:30
Monday 18:00 - 23:30
Tuesday 18:00 - 23:30
Wednesday 18:00 - 23:30
Thursday 18:00 - 23:30
Friday 18:00 - 23:30
Saturday 18:00 - 23:30
```

En El Javascript tengo:

```
var hour_start = 14;
var hour_end = 15;

function comprobarHora(fecha){
  var time = fecha.getHours();
  alert(fecha.toLocaleTimeString()
    + (time>=hour_start && time<hour_end ? ': abierto' : ': cerrado'));
}
var d = new Date();
comprobarHora(d);
```

Lo que no he podido lograr, es hacer que el javascript compruebe el dia de hoy, y tome el rago de hora que se muestra en el html.

**un ejemplo:**

Si hoy es Lunes y son las 18:00, debe mostrar una alerta de que esta abierto.

Porque en el html `Monday = 18:00 a 23:30`.

Alguna ayuda o sugerencia?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que el problema es que cada día puede tener un horario diferente.

Lo que deberías hacer es crear un array con los diferentes horarios de cada día de la semana. En mi ejemplo he puesto un mismo horario de lunes a viernes (15:00 - 23:30), otro para el sábado (20:00-23:30) y otro para el domingo (00:00 - 00:00, luego cerrado).

El valor de la hora, tanto de inicio como de fin, la establezco en número de minutos: la hora por 60 más los minutos.

He modificado la función de comprobación de la hora para que seleccione el horario correcto en función del día de la semana (que se obtiene con `getDay`) y calculando el número de minutos de la fecha de la misma forma: horas por 60 más minutos.

```js
var horarios = [
  {start: 0, end: 0 }, // domingo (no abre)
  {start: 15*60, end: 23*60 + 30}, // lunes (15:00-23:30)
  {start: 15*60, end: 23*60 + 30}, // martes (15:00-23:30)
  {start: 15*60, end: 23*60 + 30}, // miércoles (15:00-23:30)
  {start: 15*60, end: 23*60 + 30}, // jueves (15:00-23:30)
  {start: 15*60, end: 23*60 + 30}, // viernes (15:00-23:30)
  {start: 20*60, end: 23*60 + 30}, // sábado (20:00-23:30)
];

function comprobarHora(fecha){
  var day = fecha.getDay();
  var time = fecha.getHours() * 60 + fecha.getMinutes();
  console.log(fecha.toLocaleTimeString()
    + (time>=horarios[day].start && time<horarios[day].end ? ': abierto' : ': cerrado'));
}
var d = new Date(); // Día y hora actual
comprobarHora(d);
d = new Date(2017, 11, 6, 15, 38, 0); // Miércoles 15:38
comprobarHora(d);
d = new Date(2017, 11, 9, 15, 38, 0); // Sábado 15:38
comprobarHora(d);
d = new Date(2017, 11, 9, 21, 38, 0); // Sábado 21:38
comprobarHora(d);
```

Para poder indicar como hora de cierre las 12 de la noche se puede indicar la hora en segundos y establecer el cierre a las 23:59:59.

Para poder tener varios tramos en el mismo día podríamos modificar los objetos de los horarios añadiendo el día al que hacen referencia.

En este ejemplo para ver si está abierto utilizo el método `some` para comprobar si alguno de los tramos horarios cumple con las condiciones especificadas (que se corresponda con el día y la hora esté comprendida entre el inicio y el fin):

```js
var horarios = [
  {day: 0, start: 0, end: 0 }, // domingo (no abre)
  {day: 1, start: 09*60*60, end: 12*60*60}, // lunes (09:00:00-12:00:00)
  {day: 1, start: 14*60*60, end: 22*60*60}, // lunes (14:00:00-22:00:00)
  {day: 2, start: 15*60*60, end: (23*60 + 30)*60}, // martes (15:00:00-23:30:00)
  {day: 3, start: 15*60*60, end: (23*60 + 30)*60}, // miércoles (15:00:00-23:30:00)
  {day: 4, start: 15*60*60, end: (23*60 + 30)*60}, // jueves (15:00:00-23:30:00)
  {day: 5, start: 15*60*60, end: (23*60 + 30)*60}, // viernes (15:00:00-23:30:00)
  {day: 6, start: 20*60*60, end: (23*60 + 59)*60 + 59}, // sábado (20:00:00-23:59:59)
];

var weekdays = ['domingo', 'lunes', 'martes', 'miércoles', 'jueves', 'viernes', 'sábado'];

function comprobarHora(fecha){
  var day = fecha.getDay();
  var time = (fecha.getHours() * 60 + fecha.getMinutes())*60 + fecha.getSeconds();
  console.log(weekdays[day] + ' ' +
    fecha.toLocaleTimeString() +
    (horarios.some(t=> t.day===day && time>=t.start && time<t.end) ? ': abierto' : ': cerrado'));
}
var d = new Date(); // Día y hora actual
comprobarHora(d);
d = new Date(2017, 11, 6, 15, 38, 0); // Miércoles 15:38
comprobarHora(d);
d = new Date(2017, 11, 9, 15, 38, 0); // Sábado 15:38
comprobarHora(d);
d = new Date(2017, 11, 9, 23, 59, 58); // Sábado 23:59:58
comprobarHora(d);
d = new Date(2017, 11, 18, 08, 52, 0); // Lunes 08:52:00
comprobarHora(d);
d = new Date(2017, 11, 18, 11, 0, 0); // Lunes 11:00:00
comprobarHora(d);
d = new Date(2017, 11, 18, 13, 0, 0); // Lunes 13:00:00
comprobarHora(d);
d = new Date(2017, 11, 18, 17, 0, 0); // Lunes 17:00:00
comprobarHora(d);
```

Comment: Uff, esto es perfecto!! me ahorre mucho codigo sucio! Mil Gracias! tomare en cuenta para futuras cosas los array, no se me ocurrio.

Comment: como podria manejarlo a 12hrs?

Comment: Porque cuando son las 12 de la noche, no lo toma bien. usando 00

Comment: Podrías gestionar la hora en segundos en lugar de en minutos y utilizar 23:59:59

Comment: En el array, puedo colocar mas horas en un mismo dia? ejemplo, si esta cerrado de 9am a 12pm , pero abren a las 2pm hasta las 10pm?

Comment: He añadido un ejemplo de cómo podría hacerse

Comment: Y si cierra al otro día, cómo lo manejas?